# Checkmate but confused why

Tags: chess

[image]

Could someone please let me know why this is checkmate, could I not have captured that queen with my king?

Comment: For future reference, you might want to consider posting questions like this on https://chess.stackexchange.com. I'm not saying this Stack is a bad place for a chess question, I'm just saying there's a specific Stack that is better because (and only because) it's specific to the game. I'm sure I'm not the only person who is a member of both. On more difficult questions, it would likely be more appropriate or get better answer on the Chess stack, anyway. And you might learn more about chess there, too.

Comment: Migrate to [chess.stackexchange.com](https://chess.stackexchange.com/). Another benefit it has is animating the move history.

Answer (score 39):

The queen is protected by the bishop on c5, i.e. the one on the dark square. Therefore you can't capture it. As the king has nowhere else to go, and no other piece can capture the queen or interpose, it's checkmate.

[image]

Comment: Just in case: capturing the queen isn't just a losing move. It's not a move. You're not allowed to put your king in danger. Chess is very deferential to kings that way

Comment: @OwenReynolds I hope someone's made a variant without all these silly check rules, where you win by capturing the king.

Comment: @user253751 You do, though. Rather, you lose when capture of your king is inevitable.

Comment: @WeckarE. you don't *actually* capture the king. Instead, we have a bunch of silly pointless rules aiming to stop the game where the king capture would be, without actually capturing it. Imagine how much simpler the game rules would be if the capture rules for the king were exactly the same as any other piece.

Comment: We wouldn't have stalemate; that means a small material advantage would be decisive way more often.

Comment: @user253751 that would arguably take a huge portion of the strategy/skill that chess players tend to enjoy

Comment: @user253751 There are versions that use King capturing, usually ones that make it possible to survive the loss of a King somehow.  First one coming to mind is Four Kings One War on Steam (I believe it's free), where you have an extended board and control two full sets of pieces each.  Losing your first King costs you one of your two moves on your next turn, and prevents you moving pieces of that King's color with your remaining move that turn - that color is "stunned" by the loss of the King.  Losing your second King also loses you the game.

Comment: @PCLuddite: I am a chess player and I detest the possibility of stalemate. It just adds more **ad-hoc** complications to endgames, which is not appealing at all from an abstract game theory viewpoint, because there is little structural beauty there. It is like claiming that regularly playing [Chomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp) is intellectually exciting, or [16×16 chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_on_a_Really_Big_Board) is more interesting than normal chess. No, not at all.

Comment: Nitpick: "we wouldn't have stalemate" is incorrect. It would still exist, but just be way less likely to occur in a real game: https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4836/19465